# How can I change highway label icon text color on Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am struggling with styling custom Google Map embed into page. I have used [snazzymaps.com](https://snazzymaps.com) to create [custom style](https://snazzymaps.com/style/58198/cm-map). The problem is that highways icons are not legible. What I need is to change the text in the icon to be white (or as close to white as possible). I have been playing with Saturation, lightness and gamma for for a good while but with no luck.

You can see my [custom style here](https://snazzymaps.com/style/58198/cm-map). To see the issue navigate to Ireland and zoom in a bit. You will see the gray rectangles.

Comment: see this link:https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3591

Comment: this may help:http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/53355/customising-google-maps-breaks-highway-label-blocks

Comment: Thanks @Suchit. I have seen both pages you mentioned. The issue in first link seams to be similar but not exactly the same (but maybe it is the same think). I have tried the solution suggested in second link and it did help a tiny bit but I was hoping for better solution.